# Duplicate Values in Query

Tags: sql, sybase

Novice SQL user here - I am trying to determine the delivery date (de_arrdate) for an order based on event data from the events table. A shipment can have multiple events, shipments usually have 4 events so the events table will return data based on shipment ID for all 4 events. Because of this, my total $$$ is overstated. How can I return only the largest value of the shipment sequence which would essentially be the final event date? My query is below. I've also attached a sample of the current output.

```
select dba.disp_ship.ds_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_bill_charge, 
        dba.disp_ship.ds_status, dba.disp_ship.ds_ship_type, 
        dba.disp_events.de_site, dba.disp_events.de_arrdate, 
        dba.disp_events.de_shipment_id, dba.disp_events.de_ship_seq
from dba.disp_ship
    inner join dba.disp_events on dba.disp_ship.ds_id = dba.disp_events.de_shipment_id
```

Comment: If you are trying to determine the delivery date, how come you end up with "my total $$$ is overstated"? :)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Sybase? Please don't include inappropriate tags.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?noredirect=1&lq=1 for how to get the last event row for each shipment in MySQL.

Comment: There are probably similar questions for Sybase, or you could just use the same solutions as MySQL.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: while OP has mentioned `sybase` as the database in question, we need to know which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?), and preferably the version, too; the current answer makes use of a CTE but ... CTE's are not available in Sybase **ASE**, hence the need to know which Sybase RDBMS product OP is using; it would also help if OP updated the question with the criteria used to determine 'final event date', eg, is this merely the `max(event_date)` for all events, or does the query need to further limited to a specific set of 'valid' events?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which RDBMS you are using nor the version, but if I understood correctly, you only want the amount stated in the last event of the sequence, right?

In this case, you already have the order of the events in the `de_ship_seq` column, so all you need to do is:

```
with last_event as (
  select
    de.de_arrdate, 
    de.de_shipment_id, 
    max(de.de_ship_seq)
  from dba.disp_events as de
  group by 1, 2
)
select 
  ds.ds_id,
  ds.ds_bill_charge,
  ds.de_arrdate
from dba.disp_ship as ds 
join last_event as le on ds.ds_id = le.de_shipment_id
```

This way, you'll not get duplicity by the table `disp_events`, since you're only grabbing the maximum of the sequence, which it's supposed to be the last event :)

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. The RDBMS is Sybase.

Comment: So I can start the statement with "with" and enclose the statement that brings only the max  de_ship_seq and then close it and continue with the rest of the statement?

Comment: The WITH syntax is meant to start a CTE (more info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). I like to think of CTEs as subqueries with a name, since you always give them one. 

In this case, in the `last_event` subquery, we're just grabbing the maximum sequence (the last event in the sequence), and its shipment_id & arr_date. Later, what we do is just a simple RIGHT JOIN between the `disp_ship` table and the CTE query, but since we already grouped by shipment_id and arr_date, we will not have duplicates :)

Comment: Nice. I get it. Thank you for the link. The only join here that would be needed is for the CTE and the disp_ship table since the CTE is used to bring data from disp_events? Wouldn't I still need to join disp_events because de_arrdate is in the query?

Comment: Check the query inside the CTE: we're already grabbing the de_arrdate from disp_events :)

Comment: I don't think the RDBMS I am using (Sybase) supports CTE. What would be the equivalent to CTE for Sybase?

Comment: Looks like you can, though: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbusage/ug-commontblexpr.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this scenario.

**1. Inner Query**

```
select dba.disp_ship.ds_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_bill_charge, 
        dba.disp_ship.ds_status, dba.disp_ship.ds_ship_type, 
        dba.disp_events.de_site, dba.disp_events.de_arrdate, 
        dba.disp_events.de_shipment_id, dba.disp_events.de_ship_seq
from dba.disp_ship
    inner join dba.disp_events on dba.disp_ship.ds_id = dba.disp_events.de_shipment_id,
inner Join (Select a.de_shipment_id as shipid,max(a.de_arrdate) as arrdate 
            from disp_events a) as t on dba.disp_events.de_shipment_id = t.shipid and dba.disp_events.de_arrdate = t.arrdate
```

**2. Procedure**

```
//Datatype for the Temporary tables is an assumption. Replace with your data type.
begin
declare local temporary table tbl1(
   ds_id numeric(10),
   ds_bill_charge numeric(14,2), 
   ds_status int,
   ds_ship_type int, 
   de_site char(20),
   de_arrdate date, 
   de_shipment_id numeric(10),
   de_ship_seq numeric(10)
)on commit preserve rows;
declare local temporary table tbl1(
    rowid numeric(10);
    shipmentid numeric(10)
)on commit preserve rows;
declare @rowcount,@ds_id,i numeric(10);

set i = 1;
insert into tbl1
select dba.disp_ship.ds_id, dba.disp_ship.ds_bill_charge, 
        dba.disp_ship.ds_status, dba.disp_ship.ds_ship_type, 
        dba.disp_events.de_site, dba.disp_events.de_arrdate, 
        dba.disp_events.de_shipment_id, dba.disp_events.de_ship_seq
from dba.disp_ship
    inner join dba.disp_events on dba.disp_ship.ds_id = dba.disp_events.de_shipment_id;

insert into tbl2
select number(*), ds_id from(select distinct ds_id from tbl1) a;

select count(*) into @rowcount from tbl2;

while i <= @rowcount Loop
   Select ds_id into @ds_id from tbl2 where rowid = i;
   delete from tbl1 where ds_id = @ds_id and 
                de_ship_seq not in(select top 1 de_ship_seq from tbl1 a
                                   where a.ds_id = @ds_id order by de_arrdate desc);
   i++;
end Loop;
select * from tbl1;
end
```

Thank You...